# Maximum call stack size exceeded avoiding this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have read lots of topics talking about the same thing but none of them actually helped me.

This is my body code:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='main'>
        <div class='header'></div>
        <div class='image'>
            Pick image
        </div>
        <div style='clear: both'></div>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="file" id="file">
```

And in the jQuery I have (**this works**):

```
$(".image").click(function(){
    $("#file").click();
});
```

But this, as expected, only works for the first `.image` click. If I clone the `.main`, the click event on `.image` will not work anymore. So, to solve that problem I need to implement `$(document)`, which was what I did.

```
$(document).on('click', $(".image"), function(event){
    $("#file").click();
});
```

Although this piece of code does not work an retrieves the error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Some searches around the goolge told me to use `event.stopPropagation();` after the `.click()`, but it does not work either.

Comment: The second argument to `.on()` shold be a string containing a selector, not a jQuery object.

Comment: First thing no need to wrap selector in `$` here,  `$(document).on('click', ".image", function(event){`

Comment: instead use ".image" only ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect, it should be:

```
$(document).on('click', ".image", function(event){
    $("#file").click();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the line:

```
$(document).on('click', $(".image"), function(event){
    $("#file").click();
});
```

To:

```
$(document).on('click', '.image', function(event) {
    $("#file").click();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this]

Change your code from this

```
$(".image").click(function(){
    $("#file").click();
});
```

TO

```
   $(document).on('click','.image',function(){
        $("#file").click();
    });
```